# Is it possible to disable firefox error messages during karma tests

Tags: javascript, firefox, jasmine, karma-runner, indexeddb

I'm running tests with jasmine/karma and although all tests run ok, process exits with 1. I suspect that these are Firefox's web console error messages, which are produced when I try to add existing record into IndexedDB object store. Is there any option to disable these messages or ignore them in Karma runner?

UPD: These errors occur in web console even if I wrap my code inside try..catch, so it's browsers default behaviour.

https://travis-ci.org/1999/sklad/builds/36609101

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs this. The answer is [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=872873#c6). In brief, Firefox shows that this is a usual DOM error and it has default behavior. So if you prevent default 'onerror' behavior which is 'abort', everything goes fine. You can see the result [here](https://travis-ci.org/1999/sklad/builds/36615022).